# How can i check if other users copied my folder?

Tags: linux, centos

Last week, I assign a new user, and I forgot to forbid the user to visit the folder. After two days, I found it, and forbid his access at once.
I want to know if he copied my folder.

It is a Gnu/Linux server which has several user on it.
I am the root.

I can use `history` to search his command history.
But, I know he may use some ftp client software.
So, how can I know if he copied my folder or not?

Comment: You can by setting up auditing before the fact. Perhaps it is configured already? Then check the audit logs. If not, I am afraid it's very unlikely you will find traces of what users have done. You could check access times of your files, but if even if you find they were accessed in the right time window, it would be very weak evidence. If there are no recent access times, and your files/directories are read-only, I would say you are safe.

Comment: *So, how can i know is he copied my floder or not?* You can't.

Comment: "_i forgot to forbid the user to visit the folder._" why not close off permissions for the folder so that _by default_ no-one can access it?

Comment: He copied your porn. Let it be. :-)

Comment: A history-file can be easily changed. If your filesystem has one you can check the journal. Remember that after it's copied there is nothing that can be done to undo it

Answer (score 2):

Even if you have no auditing software installed. The file-system is probably configured to record the time of the most recent read. It won't tell you who. But it may be useful. (If you have read the files most recently then that is the time that you will find). Note it is the file read, not the file-name/directory read (these have there own read time).

If you have not got an auditing system. Then try these solutions.

Solution 1)
Easy to describe, hard to do

- Search every computer, hard-disk, SSD, CD, tape, … in the world for your data.

Solution 2)
Easy to describe, easy to do, hand to want to do

- Stop worrying: there is nothing that you can do, and worrying will not change it.
- Learn from your mistakes.
- If it is a GDPR breach, then report it.

Solution 3)

- Ask